# How do I change the file save type in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

How do I convert back to new file format from compatibility mode?

Comment: try the "save as" menu

Comment: It is a simple question, yes, but unless it is a duplicate, it is still valid. Just becuase you may already know this answer does not mean it is not constructive for those who don't.

Answer (score 7):

Use the "Save As..." option, either in the quick access toolbar or in the File section and make sure to set the "Save As" type to "Word Document (*.docx)".

Selecting "Word 97-2003 document" as the file type will leave the file in the older format requiring compatibility mode.

**Changing default "Save As" type:**

If you want to change the default file save as type in Word 2007/2010 (this will only affect newly created documents, not ones that have already been created and saved and are only being edited currenctly):

In the File section, open Options. In the Save section, set "Save files in this format" to the desired default format.

Comment: Shortcut key for Save As ... dialog - F12